# SteVe OCPP Custom Message

Tags: json, websocket, ocpp

I recently started using SteVe to simulate a CPO (Charging Point Operator) backend to interact with my charger and send OCPP messages, since it's completely free and open source. On SteVe there are pre-configured WSS requests, but my charger is equipped with a display and I would like to use the "DataTransfer" message to transfer a message that modifies the QR-Code that can be seen on the display after a transaction. For example:

```
"{\"type\": \"ChargeQRCodeConfig\", \"ChargeQRLabel\": \"INTERCHARGEEVERYWHERE\"，\"ChargeQRUpdate\": \"TACR1234567S0001\"，\"ChargeQRInfo\": \"TACR1234567S0001\"， \"ChargeQRGraphics\": \"False\"}"
```

Do you know if it is possible to create/add a custom request on SteVe?
If not, do you have any other ideas or alternatives?

I've tried to search on the official GitHub documentation, but haven't found anything.

Thanks!